# Custom file upload control in sapui5

Tags: file-upload, sapui5

Output

[image]

I want to make file upload control on click of image.
file uploader should open on click of image.

```
<HBox class="assetImgBlock">
    <VBox class="uploadAssets">
        <Image width="7rem" class="hdrTitl" src="./images/WearableProtection.jpeg" press="fnOpenUploader"></Image>
        Input value="Head"></Input>
    </VBox>
    <VBox class="uploadAssets">
        <Image width="7rem" class="hdrTitl" src="./images/Ladders.jpeg"></Image>
        <Input value="Body"></Input>
    </VBox>
    <VBox class="uploadAssets">
        <Image width="7rem" class="hdrTitl" src="./images/bucketSecured.jpeg"></Image>
        <Input value=""></Input>
    </VBox>
</HBox>
```

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Can you provide your fnOpenUploader code?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a fragment contains file uploader, and trigger it by clicking on image.